# 'car' dependency error: Installing caret in R 3.1.2

Tags: r, installation, package, r-caret, r-car

Cannot install caret package !!

```
install.packages("caret")
Installing package into ‘/home/timekeeper/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning: dependency ‘car’ is not available
trying URL 'http://mirrors.softliste.de/cran/src/contrib/caret_6.0-52.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3665293 bytes (3.5 Mb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 3.5 Mb

ERROR: dependency ‘car’ is not available for package ‘caret’
* removing ‘/home/timekeeper/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.1/caret’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpLbNFrr/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("caret") :
  installation of package ‘caret’ had non-zero exit status
```

When I install 'car' package separately, it says:

```
install.packages("car")
Installing package into ‘/home/timekeeper/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning message:
package ‘car’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)
```

I am using

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) -- "Pumpkin Helmet"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

I downgraded to R 3.1.2 from 3.2 since I was getting some compatibility issues.
Is there any way to use caret without upgrading to R 3.2 as 'car' package is for >= R 3.2.

Comment: Install an archive: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/car/
But your really should upgrade R

Comment: Just want to +1 @Pascal's comment. Upgrading R took care of issues with the car and caret packages.

Comment: Since I required R 3.1 also, I have managed to install both R 3.1 and R 3.2 and car and caret both are working fine now.

Comment: @AayushKumarSingha how did you solve the problem? I also need to work on R 3.2.0 and I can not install caret as it needs car!