# Cannot Install Caret

Tags: r, r-caret

I've been looking at StackOverflow forums like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32261094/car-dependency-error-installing-caret-in-r-3-1-2) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32261094/car-dependency-error-installing-caret-in-r-3-1-2) but I cannot find a problem.

What I'm having an issue with is that I cannot install the `caret` package because the dependencies cannot be installed. I even tried to run `install.packages("caret", dependencies = T)` and that failed. I have also tried `install.packages("caret", dependencies = c("Depends", "Suggests"))` and it failed on installing `rPython` dependencies.

There seems to be issues saying that there is a configuration script and that I need to manually configure it.

I tried installing `car`, `lme4`, and other dependencies manually but only `ggplot2` was able to be installed correctly. I have no idea what else to do, below is my session Info. Please help!

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] codetools_0.2-14

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.2      data.table_1.9.6 chron_2.3-47
```

Comment: Better to report what is the error with `install.packages("rPython", dep = TRUE)`.

Comment: I just get an error saying `package ‘rPython’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)`

Comment: Yes, it seems this package is not available for Windows: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rPython/index.html

Comment: So am I screwed with `caret` then?

Comment: I have `caret` installed without `rPython` on my computer. But I guess `install.packages("caret", dependencies = T)` and `install.packages("caret", dependencies = c("Depends", "Suggests"))` failed in a different way, as `rPython` is a *suggested* package. What error do you get with `install.packages("caret", dependencies = T)`?

Comment: @Minh Mai http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa goes over various strategies to overcome (or not) this. Not specific to caret but R generally.

Comment: @Pascal when installing with `dependecies = T`, all of the packages have a zero exit status and failed to install.

Comment: Issues with Windows CRAN mirrors have been reported yesterday. Maybe try different mirrors.

Answer (score 0):

did you try downloading the packages manually from CRAN and installing them manually from Rstudio? Some of the packages require rebooting the Rstudio after package installation or after package inclusion in the Rscript. That worked for me..

also, try installing different versions of the packages until one of them works for your case..that's what I did in the case of "ggvis package